# How to fix Radio input and ng-repeat not working in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Here my controller file is

```
'use strict'

angular.module('app.maps.ctrls', [])

.controller('radCtrl', [
'$scope'
($scope) ->
        $scope.radio=[
            {value:1,select:true},
            {value:2,select:false},
            {value:3,select:false}
        ]

])
```

and the HTML mark up is

```
  <div class="page">
     <div class="panel panel-default">    
        <h4>Please choose the radio</h4>
     <div ng-controller="radCtrl" ng-repeat="item in radio">        
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio.value" name="value"/>
    </div>
<label>Sample page</label>
```

have any idea? how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are repeating `item in radio`. try `ng-model="item.select"`

here is an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/tc8pp91u/

Comment: it is not working ..have any other idea using radio button with the help of repeater?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but I've updated the answer with an example that works. You can use it as a reference.